# How to run logicapp standard on different environments without editing parameters.json file

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

We have parameterized our `connections.json` file by adding configurations in the `parameters.json` file.

So now we have this:

**connections.json**

```
{
    "AzureBlob-2": {
        "displayName": "iam-automation-builtin-blob-mi-2",
        "parameterValues": "@parameters('blob-connection-parameter-values')",
        "serviceProvider": {
            "id": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
        }
    }
}
```

**parameters.json**

```
{
    "blob-connection-parameter-values": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": {
            "authProvider": {
                "Type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
            },
            "blobStorageEndpoint": "@appsetting('AzureBlob_blobStorageEndpoint')"
        }
    }
}
```

**parameters.development.json**

```
{
    "blob-connection-parameter-values": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": {
            "connectionString": "@appsetting('AzureBlob_connectionString')"
        }
    }
}
```

This requires us to edit `parameters.json` file before running it in a different environment. Is there a way to avoid this?

We need ability to run logicapp on all environments without changing `parameters.json` file manually. Something like we can do in MVC app with `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure DevOps pipelines to build and release, you can use File transform task to change the authentication type:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I need. Unfortunately, we are using GitHub actions, not Azure Devops. But this gives me hope that it is doable. `appsetting.json` and `appsetting.development.json` way would have been great, but at least something is better than nothing for now.